# Is there a way to automatically rerender a div when the value of another changes in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components related as parent and child. In the child component I have a state dropdown that affects the value in another dropdown(city dropdown). I'm basically trying to render the region dropdown based on the value of the state dropdown. Also note, the value for state dropdown is saved in the parent component.

The issue I'm facing now is, the city dropdown doesn't get updated when the state dropdown does, irrespective of me comfortably logging the value of the city. It however only gets updated when I manually get to rerender the page maybe by reloading or refreshing the webpage.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
 let city = []

    const [region, setRegion] = useState([])

    const setCity = () =>{
        setRegion(city)
    }
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (props.location === 'rivers') {
            city = rivers_location
        }
        if (props.location === 'abia') {
            city = abia_location
        }
        if (props.location === 'bayelsa') {
            city = bayelsa_location
        }
        setCity()
    }, []);
```

Region Dropdown:

```
<div className="max-width">
                    <label htmlFor="products">Region</label>
                    <Dropdown placeholder='region' fluid selection options={region} name="region"
                              onChange={props.dropDownChange}
                    />
                </div>
```